# Any idea why I am getting duplicated cells in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Hi there can anyone tell me why am getting a duplicate on the following code in cell c3

I am getting this anytime a new form was added

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get information about the edited cell
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  var cell = e.range;
  var cellAddress = cell.getA1Notation();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  
// You can add any logic you'd like here. For example:
  
// Check if the edited cell is in a specific range 


  // Show a dialog box
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  
//ui.alert("Cell " + cellAddress + " has been modified!");
  //ui.alert("Lastrow: " + lastRow)


  //Get event values
  var thecolumn = e.range.getColumn();
  var therow = e.range.getRowIndex();
  var thevalue = e.range.getValue();
// Hideing after resolved and duplicate
  if ((thecolumn == 10) && (sheetName == 
"Response"
) && ((thevalue == "Resolved" ) || (thevalue == 
"Duplicate"
 ))) {
    // Code to remove line, else do nothing

     //ui.alert("Value is:" + thevalue);

     sheet.hideRows(therow);
    
  }
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Get the form response
  var formResponse = e.response; 

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();



  var sortRange = sheet.getRange("A3:L" + lastRow);
  var sortColumn = 1; 
// Adjust the column number to sort by 
  sortRange.sort({ column: sortColumn, ascending: false }); 

  //center the column data
  var range = sheet.getRange("D3:J3"); // Adjust the range as needed
  range.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
 
}
```